# How to sort table with images jquery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I'm trying to sort a table column whether it contains `img` or not. So my table html looks something like this :

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span class="raw"><img src="path/to/image.png" /></span></td>
<td><span class="raw">text 1</span></td>
<td><span class="raw">text 2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="raw"></span></td>
<td><span class="raw">text 4</span></td>
<td><span class="raw">text 5</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="raw"><img src="path/to/image.png" /></span></td>
<td><span class="raw">text 22</span></td>
<td><span class="raw">text 111</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How would I sort table structure like this? With end result of sort being, the columns with image on the top or on the bottom and vice-versa

I'm using this plugin :

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: The DataTables plugin might be a good solution for you. It has a lot of great features, out of the box and it has a custom sorting plugin --- http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

Comment: @Batfan thanks, I don't have a luxury of picking the new plugin at this time, I'll just to have to make it work

Answer (score 11):

Tablesorter is a great plugin - you can sort the images by the "alt" text, by defining your own text extraction function like this:

```
$("#table_id").tablesorter({
    textExtraction:function(s){
        if($(s).find('img').length == 0) return $(s).text();
        return $(s).find('img').attr('alt');
    }
});
```

Cells that do not contain images will be sorted by the text.

(*) Credit to the [jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tablesorter-sort-image) for this answer

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do would be to add hidden content to the image cells ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/347/)):

```
$(function () {
  $('table img').each(function () {
    $(this).after('<span style="display:none">1</span>');
  });

  $('table').tablesorter();
});
```

Also, since it looks like you're doing alphanumeric sorting, you might want to try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/). It will correctly sort "text 22" after "text 4".

Comment: & in clean & fast jquery that will become $("table").tablesorter().find("img").after('<span class="setstyleincss">111</span') although using the events provided by tablesorter will keep the dom lighter (in case for example table object is used by other functions then you may not want to have to deal with those extra span every time

Comment: @mikakun The only problem with using events to prepend/remove elements is if the table is huge. Then every cell gets a DOM manipulation making the sort that much slower. Honestly, I think the best solution would be to just parse the img cell data, but again you can't do that with the original version of tablesorter. In my fork of tablesorter, you can access the cell content from within the parser - see the format function: `format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex)` ([demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-advanced.html))

Comment: then that's not a problem because we are talking about a table on a webpage; the problem with a huge table would be "why appending huge table in a webpage ?" javascript is there to deal with huge data & user interaction & append to the dom only what's need to be shown

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table").tablesorter().on("sortStart",function() { 
                  //prepend a sortable string before the image
            }).on("sortEnd",function() { 
                  //remove added string
         });
```